# Set image to null when button is pressed

Tags: jquery, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `MVC` application where the user can upload an image. This is being saved in the database as a `varbinary(max)`. Right now it's not possible to delete the image. The user can only upload a new one.

How can I set the image to `null` or delete it with a `jquery` function when a button is pressed but still staying on the page?

**[Edit]**
I'd like to remove the image client side, and when the pages gets posted back to the controller, i'll be able to read the value of the image. And then save everything else, without making an extra call to the database.

**[Edit2]**
This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var item = repository.GetItem(id);

        string base64 = null;

        if (item.Image != null)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(item.Image.ToArray()))
            {
                base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        ViewData["Image"] = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(base64) ? String.Format("data:image/png;base64, {0}", base64) : String.Empty;

        return View(item);
    }
```

This is a part of the view:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item.Image)
 @if (@Model.Item.Image != null) 
 {
    <img src="@ViewData["Image"]" id="removeImage" />
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Image")
    @Html.ActionLink("delete", null, null, new { id = "deleteImage" })
 }
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

This is the script that hides the image when `ActionLink` is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#deleteImage').click(function () {
        $('#removeImage').hide();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When the `ActionLink` gets pressed, the image is being set on hide with the jquery function. And when i post this form back to the server, the image is `null`. So the question is, why does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an AJAX call. For example you could write a controller action that will delete the image from the database and then invoke this action using an AJAX call:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    if (repository.Delete(id))
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

    return Json(new { success = false });
}
```

Then you could have an anchor in the view:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete image",              // link text
    "Delete",                    // action name
    new { id = "123" },          // route values - put the id of the image here
    new { @class = "delete" }    // html attributes
)
```

that you could AJAXify:

```
$(function() {
    $('.delete').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    alert('The image was successfully deleted');
                } else {
                    alert('An error occurred and the image was not deleted');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I'd like to do this without an extra database call, because the site is heavily used. but i did upvoted it.

Comment: You want to remove an image from the database without making a database call? Did I misunderstood something from your question?

Comment: Hi, no you got me correct, setting the image null client side, makes me able to save the image as null in the database with everything else with one database call. I updated my question.

Comment: Then simply remove the corresponding file `<input>` field from when the button is clicked. This way no file will be uploaded to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: What if the user mis-clicked? Instead of deleting, he wanted to upload a different image? I rather make the image null and post that to the controller.

Comment: For obvious security reasons you cannot manipulate the value of a file input field using client side scripting. You can add or remove input elements though.

Comment: I've managed to get it working by hiding the img tag using jquery and an ActionLink. Just by hiding it, the image gets posted to the controller as null. But why does this work? I'm only hiding it?

Comment: Without specific code sample it is very hard to be objective. Sometimes a code snippet is worth hundredth words.